# Random integers (no permutation)

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

Let’s say that I have this working example:

```
lover_bound = 10;
upper_bound = 180;
steps = 10;
NumeroCestelli = 8; 

livello = [lover_bound:steps:upper_bound];
L = length(livello);
n_c = ceil((factorial(L+NumeroCestelli-1))/(factorial(NumeroCestelli)*factorial(L-1)));

randIdxs = randi([1,L],n_c,NumeroCestelli);
PianoSperimentale = single(livello(randIdxs));
```

I need to perform an `n_c x NumeroCestelli` matrix (called `PianoSperimentale`) where each row is unique. It's not allowed any form of permutation. Using randi I can't perform what I'm asking.

```
[10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80] is equal to [80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10]
```

`PianoSperimentale` should be a `1081575x8` matrix. In the past I was using the [Combinator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24325-combinator-combinations-and-permutations)) function but is very slow for very large matrix.

```
[PianoSperimentale] = combinator(L,NumeroCestelli,'c','r');

for i=1:L
    PianoSperimentale(PianoSperimentale==i)=livello(i);
end
```

So, there is a way to perform the same matrix that `combinator` do but with `randi` speed?

EDIT: I allow the same number to be chosen twice (`NumberOfCombinations = (NumeroCestelli+L-1)!/(NumeroCestelli!(L-1)!`)

**proposed edit**

I need to generate the complete set of combinations (with duplicates) obtained when choosing any 8 numbers from a vector of 18 elements. This can be done by using the [Combinator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24325-combinator-combinations-and-permutations) function but is very slow for very large matrix. Can anyone suggest a faster way to generate this?

**Example:** using "sample 3 from vector of 4" would yield the following result:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 1 4
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 3
1 3 4
1 4 4
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 2 4
2 3 3
2 3 4
2 4 4
3 3 3
3 3 4
3 4 4
4 4 4
```

I know that for a vector of 18 elements from which 8 are chosen, I will get a total of `(18+8-1)!/8!*(18-1)!` possible combinations, or 1081578 rows of 8 values. Can anyone help me find a fast algorithm to do this?

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: @Dan I need to perform an `n_c x NumeroCestelli` matrix [...] where each row is unique w/o using combinator.

Comment: @Dan I think gmeroni needs to randomly generate rows of numbers, where each generated row is unique "modulo" permutations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "historical" reasons, I am writing a new answer rather than deleting my old one (a lot of the back and forth of that question was a necessary preamble to understand the question, so that this answer even makes sense). TL;DR: FULL CODE AT THE END.

This was a really tricky problem, but I think I've got it. The key insight was the fact that your expression for the correct number of elements in your result matrix, `(L+H-1)!/(H!(L-1)!)`, strongly suggested that there is a relationship between "choose H from L + H - 1", and the solution to your problem. Trick was finding that relationship. I did this by first writing out the result of `combnk(5, 3)` (at this size, you can write out all the combinations by hand and look for patterns):

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 4 5
3 4 5
```

How do we convert this to the unique combinations of `1 2 3` (including repeats)? I noticed that there were three sets that had consecutive digits:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
```

That gave me the idea that I needed to do something with the difference of numbers in a row - that somehow, if the difference was 1, I needed to repeat the number. This insight quickly led to the following code:

```
L = 3; % pick three numbers
H = 3; % from three numbers: 1,2,3

a = combnk(1:L+H-1, L);  % generate all "combinations" of 1,2,3,4,5 without repeats

% the "magic" line: compress into "combinations with repeats"
b = cumsum([a(:,1)  diff(a,[],2) - 1],2);
```

For the above example, this gives

```
 1 1 1
 1 1 2
 1 1 3
 1 2 2
 1 2 3
 1 3 3
 2 2 2
 2 2 3
 2 3 3
 3 3 3
```

How did that happen? Well, the `diff` of a (along the second dimension) is

```
 1 1
 1 2
 1 3
 2 1
 2 2
 3 1
 1 1
 1 2
 2 1
 1 1
```

So `diff(a,[],2)-1)` is

```
 0 0
 0 1
 0 2
 1 0
 1 1
 2 0
 0 0
 0 1
 1 0
 0 0
```

In this expression, `0` means "repeat the last number", while `1` means "add 1" and `2` means "add 2". We can do all this adding by using the `cumsum` (cumulative sum) function, and by starting with the first digit of the combination. This leads to the expression

```
b = cumsum([a(:, 1) diff(a, [], 2) - 1]);
```

As a final step, you would have to convert this back into the indices you are using. Your complete code would be

```
L = 8;
H = 18;
a = combnk(1:L+H-1, L);
b = cumsum([a(:,1)  diff(a,[],2) - 1],2);
livello = 10:10:180;
PianoSperimentale = livello(b);
```

which will create an array with the size of `b`, and the values in `livello`.

I believe this will work for you (I can't test this as I don't have Matlab on my home computer), and it will be as fast as is possible for this problem.

Comment: Very well done.  You got to the heart of the problem, your solution is very elegant, and your explanation is easy to follow.  In my sad experience, great answers like this don't get very many upvotes because no one else takes the time to read them.  The voting system is unfortunately skewed towards simple one-line answers that are easy to verify.

Comment: @nispio - thank you! A comment like that is worth 50 upvotes! Good thing I do this because I enjoy it, and not for the rep... I admit I was very pleased when I cracked this one. The equation for the correct number of "combinations", which I initially didn't believe, ultimately was the clue. There is a deep lesson somewhere in that...

Comment: @nispio - I just noticed that your suggested edit (which was perfectly correct, and thank you) was rejected by three reviewers. I have now applied that edit to my answer... (I could not figure out how to "overturn" the rejection, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to parse your question. From "no permutations" and "10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80" is equivalent to "80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10" I deduce that you need to sample 8 numbers from 18, and never the same sample twice.

This means you want to generate all possible combinations (of 8 samples from 18 possible values), and select from them. There are only 43758 ways in which you can do this; after that you will have to include permutations. Therefore, the problem as stated (if I understand it correctly) cannot be solved.

**EDIT** now that the question is updated, I think the following would be a solution:

```
lover_bound = 10;
upper_bound = 180;
steps = 10;
NumeroCestelli = 8; 

livello = [lover_bound:steps:upper_bound];
livello = [livello livello];

PianoSperimentale = combnk(livello, 8);
```

Because every number occurs twice, you can have it repeated. Unfortunately that will allow multiple "doubles" (e.g. [10 10 20 20 30 30 40 40] would be allowed) and this gets to a much larger number than your expression computed (namely, 36!/(28!8!) ~ 30M). A possible approach (allowing at most one double) is

```
livello = lover_bound:steps:upper_bound;

for ii = 1:numel(livello)
  PS(ii,:,:) = combnk([livello livello(ii)], 8);
end

PianoSperimentale = reshape(PS, [], 8);
```

This allows "one duplicate number per loop", and I believe that gets closer to the answer you had in mind, although the number of combinations will be `18 * (19!/(19-8)!8!) = 1360476`, a little bit larger than your expression. I can't test this right now as I don't have Matlab on this computer...

Comment: Nope, Let's say I have `L=3` and `H=2`. The possibile combinations w/o permutation are: `[1 1]`,`[1 2]`,`[2 2]`,`[1 3]`,`[2 3]`,`[3 3]`. The formula to compute the number of the combination is `# = (H+L-1)!/(H!(L-1)!)`

Comment: I see - you are allowing the same number to be chosen twice (`11`, `22`, `33`). That is not really how "combinations" are usually defined, so you might want to clarify that in your question. I was going with the usual C(H,L) = `H!/(H-L)!L!` formula...

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the problem reduces to "generate all combinations of 8 numbers chosen from 18, with duplicates allowed". There is nothing random about that (although you might choose to shuffle them in the end) because there are (by your equation) exactly 1081575 possible values and you want all of them. Right?

Comment: You are right, I clarified in my question. Yes, is what i need.

Comment: I don't think your expression for the number of combinations is right - see my solution and let me know what you think...

Comment: My expression I think is right. Check this [attachment](http://cl.ly/image/3B3A0u330H2J)

Comment: In your example you allow `111` - three repetitions of the same number. I had understood one duplicate was allowed. I now understand the problem better - will have to think some more...